# What is best audio player with support all browsers?

Tags: jquery, iphone, cross-browser, audio-player

What is best audio player with support all browsers? It should compatible with ipad, ipod, iphone as well. HTML5 is not supported on all browsers so i can't use it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try jwplayer http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/ although it is video player, you can use it for audio playback also, check the supported file formats http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/tech-specs/

Comment: Many thanks. I have to customize player a lot. Some one referred me to use jplayer. Please help me.